# How to calculate the pace of a person from the steps?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I developing an fitenss app and want to calculate the pace(i.e speed) of a person using the steps he will walk.
For this, I will use certain time interval.

For example, in 1 hour if a person walked 2500 steps and now calculate the pace of a person i.e he is walking slow or moderate or fast.
How pace can be achieved from steps?

Can anyone please help it out?

Thank you

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Define fast, moderate and slow. How many paces per hour do you consider to be *fast*? How many would be *moderate*?